# Show that $∏_{k=1}^{∞}(u_{k}×4k^2)/(4k^2-1)<π/2$

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

We know that $$∏_{k=1}^{∞}4k^2/(4k^2-1)=π/2$$

Let us consider a sequence $(u_{k})_{k≥1}$ such that $0≤u_{k}<1$ for all $k≥1$.

Show that $$∏_{k=1}^{∞}(u_{k}×4k^2)/(4k^2-1)<π/2$$

Comment: You make every  (positive) factor strictly smaller ...

Comment: $\Pi_k u_k\leq u_1<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac {(u_k)(4k^{2})} {4k^{2}-1} <\frac {4k^{2}} {4k^{2}-1}$ for all $k$. Just multiply these inequalities over $k  \geq 2$ and note that we have strict inequality for $k=1$.

Question of convergence of the product: Note that $u_1u_2...u_n$ is decreasing and so it has  a limit. Consider the cases when the limit is $0$ and the cases when the limit is positive to see that the intended inequality holds in all cases.

Comment: Won't the $<$ be $\leqslant$ in the limit?

Comment: @Botond Thank you for the comment. I have corrected the proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I am asking about the relation with **convergence of infinite product**.

Comment: What I mean is if $a_n < b_n$ then we can conclude that $\lim a_n \leqslant \lim b_n$ only (if they exists of course). And the new partial products are strictly less than the original ones, but won't we lose that strictness in the limit?

Comment: @Botond I have addressed that question. For the product from $2$ to $\infty$ we get $\leq$ but for $k=1$ we have strict inequality. When  you multiply these tow you get strict inequality.

Comment: @China I have adrressed the question of convergence of the product now.

Comment: I see now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Every partial product satisfies
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{u_{k} 4k^2}{4k^2-1} = (u_1 u_2 \cdots u_N)\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{ 4k^2}{4k^2-1} \le u_1 \prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{ 4k^2}{4k^2-1}
$$
so that 
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{u_{k} 4k^2}{4k^2-1} \le u_1 \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{ 4k^2}{4k^2-1} = u_1 \frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{\pi}{2} \, .
$$